# Do the gods know when they are being watched, or their name said?

Tags: greek, hera

Prayers are sent to gods, so thus, the Greeks believed that their prayers were heard to some extent. But does that extent hold true for casual conversation or when curses were said in their name?

When Zeus was with Io, he put a cloud up to hid his presence from Hera. Is this because he knew she was looking for him, or was it just a precaution?